# quad with vector limit

Tags: matlab, math

I want to use quad for a list of limits **without a for loop**. As a basic example

```
T=[1 2 3];
f=@(x)x.^2
quad(0,T(1),f)
```

Calculate what I need, but I want to save quad(0,T(1),f) quad(0,T(2),f) quad(0,T(3),f) as a vector. Probably, it is a basic thing but I couldn't find any solution.
I'm thankful for any help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `arrayfun`:

```
T=[1 2 3];
f=@(x)x.^2
Q = arrayfun(@(x) quad(f,0,x), T);
```

*Note that your post has the arguments to `quad` in an incorrect order.

Comment: I like `arrayfun`, and use it a lot - but remember that in cases like this (where the function is complicated) that really all you're doing is hiding the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is only here for variety.  You could try this [Matlab Central entry](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33).  As stated on the posting, it's the only vectorized numerical method like this I've seen.