# vector valued limits in matlab integral

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to use vector limits for any matlab function of integration? I have to avoid from for loops because of the speed of my program. Can you please give me a clue on do

```
k=0:5
f=@(x)x^2
quad(f,k,k+1)
```

If somebody need, I found the answer of my question:[quad with vector limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636660/quad-with-vector-limit)

Comment: but do you just mean the integral between `0` and `5` as integrative limits?

Comment: It's exactly the same solution I gave you below

Answer (score 1):

I will try giving you an answer, based on my experience with `quad` function.

Starting from this:

```
k=0:5;
f=@(x) x.^2;
```

Notice the difference in your `f` definition (incorrect) and mine (correct).

If you only mean to integrate `f` within the range `(0,5)` you can easily call

```
quad(f,k(1),k(end))
```

Without handle function, you may reach the same results in a different way, by making use of `trapz`:

```
x = 0:5;
y = x.^2;
trapz(x,y)
```

If, instead, you mean to perform a step-by-step integration in the small range `[k(i),k(i+1)]` you may type

```
arrayfun(@(ii) quad(f,k(ii),k(ii+1)),1:numel(k)-1)
```

For a sake of convenince, notice that

```
sum(arrayfun(@(ii) quad(f,k(ii),k(ii+1)),1:numel(k)-1)) == quad(f,k(1),k(end))
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I meaned step by step integration. Thank you for your response, but I think putting "ii"s bring me also to some "loop" which I want to avoid:(

Comment: generally `arrayfun` is a good compromise to speed up a MATLAB code. btw, perhaps there several alternative way to those I suggested.